# Appbar MenuItem onClick Works on Desktop but not on Mobile, Material UI Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navbar, menuitem

In my `reactjs` app that uses `Material UI`, I have a `Appbar` with a dropdown menu in the upper righthand corner. The `onClick` for each `MenuItem` fires correctly on desktop, but does not fire on mobile. The issue occurs on all browsers. Does anyone know how to make the onClick event fire on mobile?

Here is my code:

```
const settings = ['Profile', 'FAQ', 'Logout']
```

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
   <Tooltip title="Open settings">
      <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} }}>
         <Avatar alt="profile pic" src={profPicDefault} />
      </IconButton>
   </Tooltip>
   <Menu
     id="menu-appbar"
     anchorEl={anchorElUser}
     anchorOrigin={{
       vertical: 'top',
       horizontal: 'right',
     }}
     keepMounted
     transformOrigin={{
       vertical: 'top',
       horizontal: 'right',
     }}
     open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
     onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
   >
     {settings.map((setting, i) => (
        <MenuItem key={i} onClick={handleNavClick}>
           <Typography>{setting}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
     ))}
   </Menu>
</Box>
```

```
const handleNavClick = (event) => {
    const pageName = event.currentTarget.innerText.toLowerCase()
    navigate(`/${pageName}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, on mobile, `pageName` includes a new line at the end that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

This is how I ended up fixing it:

```
if (pageName.includes('login') {
   navigate(`/${pageName}`)
}
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why the navigate statement works with pageName inside it, but `if (pageName === 'login')` doesn't work because pageName includes a new line...

If someone else has a less convoluted solution, I'd love to see it. For now, though, this works.